# iphone : memory management with dispatch_async

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function which uses `dispatch_async`

```
- (void)_handleMessage:(id)message{
    dispatch_async(_callbackQueue, ^{
        [self.delegate webSocket:self didReceiveMessage:message];
    });
}
```

I am calling this function like this

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:frameData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self _handleMessage:str]
//[str release];  <== Can I release str here???
```

My question is

- Where can I release variable `str`?

Normally I can release just after the call `[self _handleMessage:str]`, but since dispatch_async executes the statement

```
[self.delegate webSocket:self didReceiveMessage:message];
```

asynchronously (possibly after some time), I am considering a bad access error. What is the best way to manage memory in this case?

If you are still having doubts, I am an old school guy, and not using ARC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>     //[str release];  <== Can I release str here???
> ```

As far as I understand, you can release the variable there. [Indeed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html):

> In a manually reference-counted environment, local variables used within the block are retained when the block is copied. Use of instance variables within the block will cause the object itself to be retained. If you wish to override this behavior for a particular object variable, you can mark it with the __block storage type modifier.

This means that the block will retain the `message` object that you use within it and it will free it when done, so you can freely release it after calling `_handleMessage`.

Comment: As conclusive an answer as it gets.. Thanks sergio.. Will accept as soon as stackoverflow allow me to do so..